# jQuery click on anything but div AND EVERYTHING INSIDE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use tis code:

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).is('#paybox')) {
    $('#paybox').hide();
  }
});
```

to hide `#paybox` when user click anywhere but `#paybox`.

But when I click on "radio" form:

```
<div id="paybox">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="dauer" value="small" checked>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="dauer" value="mid">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="dauer" value="big">
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

INSIDE the `#payboy` then `#payboy` get hidden!

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Explain your requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check whether or not your click is inside paybox or not. Something like this should work:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if($(e.target).closest('#paybox').length === 0) {
    $('#paybox').hide();
  }
});
```

So this only hides the `#paybox` element *if* the click is neither on paybox nor any node that is within the `#paybox` element.

Comment: you'd be better off just using `$(e.target).closest('#paybox').length` since `closest()` checks the element itself, as well as its ancestors

Comment: @billyonecan Yeah, the question seems to be answered here already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element#answer-3028037

Answer (score 1):

You can use `closest` or `parents` to check this as below

```js
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).is('#paybox') && $(e.target).closest('#paybox').length === 0) {
    $('#paybox').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#paybox {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="paybox">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="dauer" value="small" checked>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="dauer" value="mid">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="dauer" value="big">
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the target is a child of your div

```
// if target is not paybox and is not child of paybox
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).is('#paybox') && !$(e.target).parents('#paybox').length) {
    $('#paybox').hide();
  }
});
```